# get the sum of visible rows in a column

Tags: java, filter, jtable, sum

I have the following method

```
public void availableCapacity(){
    double total = 0.0;
    double total1 = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableR.getRowCount(); i++){
        double amount1 = Double.parseDouble((String) tableR.getValueAt(i, 10));
        double amount = Double.parseDouble((String) tableR.getValueAt(i, 11));
        total += amount;
        total1 += amount1;
    }
    System.out.println(total +" " + total1);
    sumavailbleField.setText(Double.toString(total));
}
```

This currently gets the sum of all the rows in column 10 and column 11. This works fine. However i have a user input field which filters the table. I then want to sum the filtered rows, how can i go about doing this?

Comment: how does the user input field filter the row?  Where do you get the values into your program?

Comment: @ Daniel Widdis the values come in from an api, and the data is all tabulated into a JTable Model. The user simply enters a date and time into JTextField which filters the rows depending on input.

Answer (score 0):

i came across the same problem on the way, here's how i managed to fix it (even though it's a bit late)

```
public void availableCapacity(JTable tableR){
double total = 0.0;
double total1 = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < tableR.getRowCount(); i++){
        try{
    double amount1 = Double.parseDouble((String) tableR.getValueAt(i, 10));
    total1 += amount1;
        }catch(Exception ex){System.err.println("ex badNumberInput:"+ex);}

        try{
    double amount = Double.parseDouble((String) tableR.getValueAt(i, 11));
    total += amount;
        }catch(Exception ex){System.err.println("ex badNumberInput:"+ex);}

}

System.out.println(total +" " + total1);

BigDecimal nr = new BigDecimal(total);
String roundedResult = nr.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toString();
sumavailbleField.setText(roundedResult);
}
```

then i've added this documentListener to a jTextField in order to get tableR values

```
public void jLabelFilter(JTable tableR){

TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(tableR.getModel());   
tableR.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

//jtfFilter is the jTextField from user input    
jtfFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String text = jtfFilter.getText();
            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                availableCapacity(tableR);

            } else {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                availableCapacity(tableR);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String text = jtfFilter.getText();
            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                availableCapacity(tableR);
            } else {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                availableCapacity(tableR);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
    });    
}
```

hope it helps , cheers !